# In celery 5.0, is there a method we can start celery in code?

Tags: python, celery

less than V 5.0, we can start celery like this: celery = Celery(***), celery.start(argv)
but with upgrading to 5.0. "start" was removed, So i want to know ,how can we start worker in our code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running via

```
app = Celery(main=__name__, broker=config.REDIS_TASKS_BROKER, backend=config.REDIS_TASKS_BACKEND)
worker = app.Worker()
worker.start()
```